# DirectorySlash Off doesn't work

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm using apache 2.4.7

This is my virtualhost's config:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/login
ServerName login.mydomain.com
<Directory "/var/www/login">
    allow from all
    AllowOverride All
    Options +Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    DirectorySlash Off
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

In my `/var/www/login` directory, I have a directory called `freeseat` and in there, there's the `index.php` file, so it's full location is `/var/www/login/freeseat/index.php`

When I try to access it through the following link (domain replaced), it redirects to the same URL with a trailing slash:
http://login.mydomain.com/freeseat -> http://login.mydomain.com/freeseat/

Why isn't the `DirectorySlash Off` working? I tried to put it in `.htaccess`, but that didn't help either.

Thanks a lot for your help,

David

Comment: It works well, but without trailing slash you may get wrong links in the directory listing. Disable the browser cache while testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you vHost won't work if you don't use the  directive.
This works:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/login
    ServerName login.mydomain.com
    <Directory "/var/www/login">
            Allow from all
            AllowOverride All
            Options +Indexes
            DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
            DirectorySlash Off
            Require all granted
    </Directory>
ErrorLog /var/www/login/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

To answer you question: DirectorySlash works as expected.

Also see apache documentation for [mod_dir](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryslash), especially the red box called "Security Warning" of section "DirectorySlash".

Tip: always use not publicly accessible error logs to determine the root of evil. :)

---

Edit #1:

I think I might have misunderstood your question. You want to access `/var/www/login/freeseat/index.php` through http://login.mydomain.com/freeseat (w/o trailing slash).

Then, drop the freeseat folder and use index.php as var/www/login/freeseat.php and create a RewriteRule in the /var/www/login/.htaccess file (mod_rewrite must be active):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^freeseat$ freeseat.php
```

Also, drop

```
Options +Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

from your vHost configuration. It isn't needed anymore.

Comment: Thanks for answering my query. The vhost is configured just like you said (I didn't include the directive, but it's the same), but the DirectorySlash doesn't work. It keeps redirecting and there's nothing in the error log to show that there's anything wrong

Comment: @Edit I guess I misunderstood your question. I'm going to expand my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. so, I enabled the `rewrite` module and set the `.htaccess` to include the 2 lines and this is my current vhost:

    <VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/login
    ServerName login.mydomain.com
    #LogLevel debug
    <Directory "/var/www/login">
     allow from all
     AllowOverride All
     DirectorySlash Off
     Require all granted
    </Directory>
    </VirtualHost>

But it still doesn't work. I get in the browser this error (and nothing in the error.log):

`The requested URL /freeseat was not found on this server.`

Comment: Them I'm completely out of options. On my system, it works just fine. Sorry I wasn't of any help, my friend.

Comment: Got another idea, lemme try a bit.

Comment: Try `^freeseat$` instead of `^/freeseat$`. My bad.

Comment: I just found myself that the / was unnecessary ;-)

Comment: BTW, If I do the following (and leave the folder with a slightly different name), it also works: RewriteRule ^freeseat$ /free_seat/index.php

Comment: I just thought a subfolder for a single file was unnecessary. Good thing you found it yourself, though.